# Assitance with checking array items and placing them in a TextView

Tags: android

I am after some advice on a method, I want to populate a list of all items in the array, then compare each item with a time and day and if they match the day and time on a tableLayout textView add the item into that TextView. I am really struggling with this and would appreciate some help.

Thanks

PS I am using an array to store the item in my app

```
 Public void getData() {
TextView MondayNine = (TextView)     (android.R.MondayNine);
 for (Timetable t: Timetables) 
 If(t.getDay().equals("Monday") && (t.getTime.equals(09:00) { MondayNine.setText(t.toString());
```

Comment: put some code, so that i can help you out!

Comment: I'm on my phone and this is what I have so far but using this format is going to be really long

Answer (score 0):

Can't say much without see your Timetable class but I'd say you're missing a getDay() before toString().

**UPDATE**

```
//Declare this field.
private String[] days = {"Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday" , "Thursday" , "Friday" , "Saturday" , "Sunday"};

for (Timetable t: Timetables) {
    for(int i = 0; i
```

And the same thing for the hours.

Comment: I am trying to see if there's a  way to simplify my code as I need to do the check above for every hour and day in the week and if a timetable exists place that in the corresponding textview

Comment: You're also missing a parenthesis.

Comment: TO simplify your code I'd write a string array with every day of the week and check each of them with a for and within that for another one for the hours.

Comment: Could you possibly please post a brief demo

Comment: But how will I set this method to assign the details to let's say three days that all have the time 0900?

Comment: Like TuesdayNine, WednesdayNine and so on? You could use an array

Comment: How would I set an array of textviews to my class?